# Reload page with #anchor without sending post data

Tags: javascript, html, forms, post, anchor

I'm struggling with refreshing a page with an anchor.

I have a page `test.php#one` and send a POST form on that page. If I confirm the alert box (I use a custom alert box),

```
this.ok = function()
{
    document.getElementById(\'dialogbox\').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById(\'dialogoverlay\').style.display = "none";
    window.location.replace(document.URL);
}
```

the box dissapears, but the page won't refresh.
I tried every result google gave me, but the page simply won't refresh, if there is an anchor in the URL.
I would be happy for any solution that will reload the page to the same anchor and won't send the POST form twice.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want.

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's ok like this, I use PHP to fire the alert box. https://jsfiddle.net/pkomgf4p/